# Create dependency from assembla repo

Tags: android, android-studio, assembla

Is it possible to create a library dependency from an assembla svn repo and use it like this:

compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'

Comment: If you use GitHub there is a service called JitPack you can use like that

Comment: So it's not possible to do it with assembla?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know about assembla.